# Error 500 ajax-upload.php Uploading avatar

Tags: ajax

When I try to upload an avatar it is always loading and gives the error "
POST ajax-upload.php 500 (Internal Server Error) " in chrome inspector

Plugin installed Ultimate Membership Pro

Code of ajax-upload.php:

```
  <?php
/*
 * Upload files via Ajax
 */

require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");

// security layer
$uid = indeed_get_uid();
$access = true;
if ( !$uid ){
        $hash = isset( $_COOKIE['ihcMedia'] ) ? $_COOKIE['ihcMedia'] : '';
    if ( empty($hash) ){
            $access = false;
        }
    $hash = esc_sql( $hash );
    $exists = \Ihc_Db::doesMediaHashExists( $hash );
    if ( !$exists ){
            $access = false;
    }
}
// end of security layer

 if ( $access ){
if (isset($_FILES['avatar'])){
    //========== handle avatar image
    if ($_FILES['avatar']['type']=='image/png' || $_FILES['avatar']['type']=='image/gif' || $_FILES['avatar']['type']=='image/jpeg'){
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';
        $arr['id'] = media_handle_upload('avatar', 0);
        if ($arr['id']){
            $arr['url'] =  wp_get_attachment_url($arr['id']);
            $arr['secret'] = md5($arr['url']);
            echo json_encode($arr);
        } else {
            echo '';
        }
    }
} else if (isset($_FILES['ihc_file'])){
    //============= handle upload file
    //debug
    //file_put_contents( "upload_media.log", $_FILES['ihc_file']['type'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php';
    $arr['id'] = media_handle_upload('ihc_file', 0);
    if ($arr['id']){
        $arr['url'] =  wp_get_attachment_url( $arr['id'] );
        $arr['secret'] = md5($arr['url']);
    }

    $arr['name'] = $_FILES['ihc_file']['name'];
    if (in_array($_FILES['ihc_file']['type'], array('image/gif','image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/png'))){
        $arr['type'] = 'image';
    } else {
        $arr['type'] = 'other';
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
}

else if (isset($_FILES['img'])){
        //// upload account page banner
        $cropImage = new Indeed\Ihc\CropImage();
        echo $cropImage->saveImage($_FILES)
                                     ->getResponse();
}

else if (isset($_POST['imgUrl'])){
        $cropImage = new Indeed\Ihc\CropImage();
        if ( isset($_POST['customIdentificator']) && $_POST['customIdentificator']=='image' ){
                $cropImage->setSaveUserMeta( false );
        }
        echo $cropImage->cropImage($_POST)
                                     ->getResponse();
}
}
```

Chrome inspector:

```
POST http://mysitename/wp-content/plugins/indeed-membership- 
pro/public/ajax-upload.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:4
(anonymous) @ croppic.js:281
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3
```

11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111